# C pointer output, not the one I expected

Tags: c, pointers

*Can somebody help me understand this behaviour... ?*

I have a snippet like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *ptr = "Hello";
    printf("%c ",++*ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected (keeping in mind the precendence order of ++ and * and R to L associativity) that the output should be

```
I    (the letter I)
```

but it is not so, rather the program crashes.

so pls somebody explain, **what am I missing here?**

Comment: You're trying to modify a string literal -- that's undefined behavior.

Comment: @Paul Hankin,  Do you mean that it is treated as const? pls explain a bit

Answer (score 1):

> char *ptr = "Hello";

ptr is string literal and you are not supposed to change it.

If you want to change, use array instead:

```
char ptr[] = "Hello";
printf("%c ",++*ptr);
```

---

Note that in your original code `char *ptr = "Hello";`, `ptr` is not a const pointer, it can change to point to something else.

Because the `"Hello"` string is stored in read-only memory, so as long as `ptr` is pointing to it, you cannot modify the data pointed by `ptr`.

Generally, however, you can change `ptr` to point to somewhere else, and the data pointed by it can be modified, eg,

```
char *ptr = "Hello";    // data cannot be modified by ptr
char arr[] = "abcd";
ptr = arr;              // data can be modified by ptr
printf("%c ",++*ptr);
```

Comment: ohk.. got it , but does it mean that *ptr is const?

Comment: How is literal being modified in OPs code ?

Comment: @ameyCU `++*ptr = ++(*ptr)` so it tries to modify the first character in that array ie `H`

Comment: @artm Ohh !! correct associativity .

Comment: @eRaisedToX regarding *ptr is const, you can check the updated answer

Answer (score -1):

Your code is almost ok, but it needs a slight modification,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *ptr = "Hello";
    printf("%c ",*(++ptr));
    return 0;
}
```

**Explanation :** *That is happening because according to your code `(++*ptr)` it will increment the value at the address pointed by `ptr`, not the ptr itself. But to increment the address stored in `ptr` we need to increment it first and then dereference that pointer to get the data stored at that value.*

Comment: ok but why can't we modify the value pointed by ptr ? I mean I did not declare it as const  ...

Comment: @eRaisedToX When you declare `char *ptr="Hello";` , it is stored in read only memory and you are not supposed to modify it.

Comment: Yes @ameyCU is correct !

Comment: @eRaisedToX Feel free to ask if you any further questions ...

Comment: @SKG ,ty , that means   int c=10;   int *ptr =&c;   printf("%d ",++*ptr); here the case is different ,,, becoz it works

Comment: yup ! you're absolutely right